# How to run a video without launching any media player?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, cocos2d-iphone, playback

I actually want to play a video (.mov) in my cocos2D game, without launching a player like a popup window and when it ends, it remove from the screen. Please answer in details. Thanks.

Comment: which cocos2d version? There is a CCVideoPlayer in the extensions project for v2.x

Comment: @LearnCocos2D my Version is 3.x, can you please guid me programatically... :)